# Proof check: does set $A$ have accumulation points?

Tags: general-topology

I´m asked to prove or disprove that:

Given the sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ assuming values in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $x_n =((1-1/n)\cos n), ((1-1/n)\sin n)$. Let $A := Im(\ (x_n)_n \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$). Then $A$ has no accumulation points.

My try:

Given that $\sin x \subseteq B_1[0]$, $\cos x \subseteq B_1[0] \ \forall \ x \in \mathbb{R}$, and given that $0 \leq (1-1/n) < 1, \forall \ n \in \mathbb{N}$, we necessarily have $x_n \subseteq B_1[0]$, so that $x_n$ is bounded by the unit ball in the origin. It follows then by the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem that $x_n$ has a convergent subsequence, so that $a$ must have accumulation points. (My question here is that the convergent sequence could still be a trivial, constant subsequence, so that the presence of accumulation points wouldn´t be proved).

My second try:

$\sin n = 0, \forall \ n = 2n$

$\sin n = 1, \ \forall \ n = 2n+1$

$\cos n = 1, \ \forall \ n = 2n$

$\cos n = 0, \ \forall \ n = 2n+1$,

$0 < (1-1/n+1) \leq (1-1/n) < 1, \forall \ n \in \mathbb{N}$

By the Archimedian Property, we can make $n$ arbitrarily big, and thus $(1-1/n)\cos n$ (wlg for $\sin n$) arbitrarily close to $\cos n$, such that, given a neighborhood $B_\epsilon(\cos 0)$, $\exists \ n_0$ such that $\cos 2n \subseteq B_\epsilon(\cos 0) \ \forall n > n_0$, so that $A$ has accumulation points.

Can someone check the answers, please? Are they, or one of them, correct? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you the correct answer, as I might be a homework problem. I will only indicate your mistakes:

- Your first approach is flawed, because Bolzano-Weierstrass applies to **infinite** bounded sets in the Euclidean space.
- In your second attempt, you need be more careful with evaluating trigonometric functions, as $\sin n\ne 0$ when $n$ is even! (There is no $\pi$ in the argument.)

Comment: But isn´t this set infinite? There will be infinite many points between -1 and 1, such as points {1/1, 1/2, 1/3, ...}.

Comment: If you can show that the set $A$ is infinite, then your first argument works. Can you show that $x_n$ has infinitely many distinct terms?